# How can I trigger custom and built in validators to validate on an ng2 template form?

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular2-template

I have an ng2 form with the following control:

```
<input class="form-field"
     type="text"
     id="fieldName"
     name="fieldName"
     #fieldName="ngModel"
     (ngModelChange)="onFieldNameChange($event)"
     [(ngModel)]="model.fieldName"
     [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
     suCustomValidator="message"
     [suAnotherCustomValidator]="booleanConditionInComponentTs">
```

(where su is the prefix for my custom components)

As part of a template form.

At what point are the validators and custom validators triggered?
How can I force this field to be validated on the change of another field an on the touch of this field?

Answer (score 1):

Since not clear about your requirement, Except for the fact that you need to have a local custom validator for each field and global validator for fields to have mutual impacts.

A good example good be `password` and `repeat password` fields

```
private buildForm(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      password: [null, Validators.required], // define password field to be mandatory (can have custom validator func call too) 
      repeat: [null, Validators.required]// define repeat password field to be mandatory (can have custom validator func call too)
    }, {validator: this.matchingPasswords('password', 'repeat')}); // have global validator to check when inputs are mades
}


private matchingPasswords(password: string, repeat: string) {
    return (group: FormGroup) => {
      const passwordIn = group.controls[password];
        const repeatIn = group.controls[repeat];
      if (passwordIn.value !== repeatIn.value) {
        return repeatIn.setErrors({notEquivalent: true});
      } else {
        return repeatIn.setErrors(null);
      }
    };
  }
```

In html templates

```
    <p *ngIf="form.get('repeat')?.errors?.notEquivalent">Passwords did not match</p>
    <p *ngIf="form.get('repeat')?.errors?.required">Confirm password is required</p>
    <p *ngIf="form.get('password')?.errors?.required">Password is required</p>
```

**Few Useful links:**

[Trigger validations on submit of forms](https://loiane.com/2017/08/angular-reactive-forms-trigger-validation-on-submit/)

[Custom validation using multiform fields](https://bertrandg.github.io/angular2-forms-form-group-validation/)

Comment: Thanks Keshan, but these are for reactive forms, rather than template forms, which I need to use for broader architectural reasons.

Comment: @StuperUser Ah gotcha! Sorry for the miss understanding. In that case you need to create a `factory` with your logic and a `directive` to bind with `html` let me update the answer, meanwhile you can refer this blog post https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/ng2-template-driven-form-validators/